# How can I add custom content to the NEW Google Sites

Tags: html, polymer, web-component, google-sites, google-sites-2016

I want to be able to add content that is served by my own server to a page on a NEW(December 2016) Google Sites site. The only way I can see of adding custom content is the 'Insert > Embed URL' option in the right hand sidebar.

I have requested support from the folks at Google G-Suite but they have provided little information, apart from suggesting that I use OpenGraph markup.

If I add a link with an image marked up with 'og' meta tags the image is displayed, which is progress, but I would like to display other content, i.e. some html that is served by my own server.

I see that the new Sites uses a version of Polymer under the covers - it would be ideal for me to serve a Polymer web component in the embedded link but I haven't been able to make that work.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I'm not sure you can display external content on Google Sites. With OpenGraph you will only display an image, a description and a title instead of your component.

Comment: On the 'old' Google Sites you certainly could embed content using apps script. What I am looking for is the equivalent functionality in the 'new' Google Sites released towards the end of 2016.

Comment: it seems that this feature is not activated yet (and not documented)

Comment: Yes it certainly seems it is not documented but whether or not it is implemented is a different matter. The open graph feature is not documented as far as I know,  but it is implemented.

Comment: The open graph doesn't seem to work for type=website so it is not fully implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google Apps Script now for this.

I don't know exactly what you were trying to embed, but a simple implementation is to create a google apps script project with a gs file and an html file.

```js
//my-gs-file.gs
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService
           .createTemplateFromFile('my-html-file')
           .evaluate(); 
}
```

```html
<!-- my-html-file.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can use javascript (with some restrictions) and google apps script for gsuite stuff https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/, external APIs https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external, etc

This is also worth a read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

I should add that this example assumes you'll go on to develop the html template with scriptlets etc, but if it's only ever going to be plain html, then the gs file need only contain the line

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('my-html-file')
```

Comment: how do you add the App Script to the Google Site? I'm getting a message saying "Some of the selected items couldn't be embedded"

Comment: Did you deploy your apps script as a web app (Publish > Deploy as web app in the apps script editor top menu)? When you do that it gives you a URL (ending /exec) which you paste into the google sites embed dialog. Also, your web app should run under your account if the script is stored somewhere only your account has access to.

Comment: This is a really fantastic answer, which already helped me. However, I have another question:

I would like to load an html to my Google site to add additional open graph tags. In particular, I would like customize the picture that is shown on social media (say Facebook) when I share a link to my page (see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91864/how-can-i-change-the-preview-image-when-sharing-a-link-on-facebook). I was trying to solve this by loading an html with the right tags, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Glad it helped :)
Rather than reply in the comments to this answer, I suggest you ask a new question which makes clear what you're trying to do - provide your code, what you've tried, any links or output, what you mean by "doesn't seem to work", etc (one very quick thought is that you might not be able to use the above answer to add html to the <head> section of the page; I think the opengraph spec requires it to be in the head - https://ogp.me/)